# Merging/updating an object in an array with another array of object with matching key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I currently have 2 different arrays of objects

```
const arr1 = [
{
  groupId: "Category",
  options: [
     {name: "cookies", id: 1111},
     {name: "tv", id: 2222}
  ]
},
{
  groupId: "Brand",
  options: [
     {name: "test1", id: 2222}
  ]
},
{
  groupId: "Price",
  options: [
     {name: "test2", id: 4444}
  ]
}
]
```

```
const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1111,
    url: "/test"
  },
  {
    id: 2222,
    url: "/test1"
  },
  {
    id: 3333,
    url: "/test2
  }
]
```

How would I merge arr2's object into arr1's object based on the matching obj ids? So for example the expected should be

```
const result = [
  {
  groupId: "Category",
  options: [
     {name: "cookies", id: 1111, url: "/test"},
     {name: "tv", id: 2222, url: "/test1"}
  ]
},
{
  groupId: "Brand",
  options: [
     {name: "test1", id: 2222, url: "/test1"}
  ]
},
{
  groupId: "Price",
  options: [
     {name: "test2", id: 4444}
  ]
}
]
```

This is what I currently have but I can't seem to get it to give me the expected result.

```
const getNewArr = (arr2, arr1) => {
    const categoryGroup = arr1.find(group => group.groupId === "Category");
    if (categoryGroup) {
      let matchGroup;
      categoryGroup.options.map(group => {
        matchGroup = arr2.filter(child =>
          child.categoryId === group.id ? {...group, child} : group
        );
      });
      return {...categoryGroup.options,...matchGroup};
    }
    return arr1;
  }
```

I tried a few things but I am unable to get it working so far. Am I missing something or is there something else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using nested `.map()` calls to iterate over each `options` array and a `.find()` call to look for relevant entries in `arr2` by id.

```js
const
  arr1 = [{ groupId: "Category", options: [{ name: "cookies", id: 1111 }, { name: "tv", id: 2222 }] }, { groupId: "Brand", options: [{ name: "random", id: 3333 }] }, { groupId: "Price", options: [{ name: "random2", id: 4444 }] }],
  arr2 = [{ id: 1111, url: "/test", other: 'other-prop' }, { id: 2222, url: "/test1" }, { id: 3333, url: "/test2" }],

  mergeById = (arr1, arr2) =>
    arr1.map(({ options, ...rest }) => (
      {
        ...rest,
        options: options.map(option => (
          {
            ...option,
            ...arr2.find(_option => _option.id === option.id)
          }
        ))
      }
    ));

const merged = mergeById(arr1, arr2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If the second array can contain multiple elements for a given id you can use `Object.assign()` and spread the result of a `.filter()` call to merge all the relevant objects.

```js
const
  arr1 = [{ groupId: "Category", options: [{ name: "cookies", id: 1111 }, { name: "tv", id: 2222 }] }, { groupId: "Brand", options: [{ name: "random", id: 3333 }] }, { groupId: "Price", options: [{ name: "random2", id: 4444 }] }],
  arr2 = [{ id: 1111, url: "/test" }, { id: 2222, url: "/test1" }, { id: 1111, other: 'other-prop' }, { id: 3333, url: "/test2" }],

  mergeById = (arr1, arr2) =>
    arr1.map(({ options, ...rest }) => (
      {
        ...rest,
        options: options.map(option => (
          Object.assign(option, ...arr2.filter(_option => _option.id === option.id))
        ))
      }
    ));

const merged = mergeById(arr1, arr2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I spent probably too many hours trying to get it to work. I can also put this to use next time I run into the same thing again! Gained some knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I see arr 2 url  should be "/test2"
and in your result array, it is missing url for id: 3333.

The main idea is just to spread all the properties existing on arr1 and add properties on the arr2 with the same id,
In the example below, first of all, I have converted arr2 into an object with id key, so later, you shouldn't use find method to access element.

```
// const arr2 = [{ id: 1111, url: "/test"}, { id: 2222, url: "/test1"}];
// will be transformed to{"1111": {url: "/test"}, "2222": {url: "/test1"}} after line below
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(({id, ...el}) => [id, el]));

const arr3 = arr1.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  options: el.options.map((oEl) => ({
    ...oEl,
    ...obj2[oEl.id],
  })),
}));
```